# Send file to printer in D language ( windows )

Tags: d

I searched the internet, somehow sending documents (txt) to the printer, but not found, how can I do to send TXT files to the printer using the D language?

Comment: like you would in C or C++ using the windows api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like ratchet freak said in the comment, it is the same way you would in C, so if you search for printing text files on Windows and find a C example, you can do it in D too. If a struct or win32 function is not available, you can add it with `extern(Windows)` and then the function signature. I know you can use a printer like any other graphics device with GDI functions, but that seems harder than it should be, idk if there's an easier way through the win32 API though.

One option: I'm not on a windows box right now, but I'm pretty sure the command `print` through the shell works on text files too and might be the easiest way. You could use `std.file.write` to write your string to a text file, then `std.process.executeShell` to call the print command on that file.

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html#.executeShell

Calling the shell to another command to do it for you might feel hackish, but hey if it gets the job done.